# Erro não detectado pelo teste do cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Estou usando a versão da gem aruba 0.13.0 e do cucumber 2.x.x

gostaria de saber como detectar o seguinte erro usando um step definition do aruba. Mais especificamente se o exit status foi de sucesso e se é possível pelo tipo de erro que está ocorrendo na execução da aplicação:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "..","lib")

require 'game'

game = Game.new
game.start

while not game.ended?
    game.next_step
end
```

O erro ocorre na hora de executar a classe acima pela lina de comando.

`bin/forca:10:in <main>': undefined methodended?' for #<'Game:0x000000012fc7d0 @output=#<'IO:<'STDOUT>>> (NoMethodError)`

Basicamente o que ele está me dizendo é que o método ended não está definido, e realmente não está, mas o cucumber não detecta o erro.

a funcionalidade é a seguinte pelo cucumber:

```rb
Funcionalidade: Começar jogo
    Para poder passar o tempo
    Como jogador
    Quero poder começar um novo jogo

    Cenário: Começo de novo jogo um sucesso
        Ao começar o jogo, é mostrada a mensagem inicial para o jogador.

        Quando começo um novo jogo
        E termino o jogo
        Então o jogo termina com a seguinte mensagem na tela:
         """
         Bem vindo ao jogo da forca!
         """
```

uso o seguinte step para prever o erro:

```
Então /^o jogo termina com a seguinte mensagem na tela:$/ do |text|
    steps %{
        Then it should pass with:
        """
        #{text}
        """ 
}
end
```

Obrigado pelo feedback e editei para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Posta sua feature e sua screen do ruby, provavelmente quando voce está chamando seu método ele não esta sendo referenciado.

Comment: Opa, desculpa a demora cara!
Pelo que vi ele não consegue achar seu método .ended? na classe Game, poderia postar a classe?

Answer (score -1):

A resposta da questão está no modo como os steps foram definidos, foi usado uma sintaxe errada para os steps definidos na própria gem aruba

```
Então /^o jogo termina com a seguinte mensagem na tela:$/ do |text|
    steps %{
        Then it should pass with:
        """
        #{text}
        """ 
}
end
```

está errado quando ficaria melhor ou no caso o correto:

```
Então /^o jogo termina com a seguinte mensagem na tela:$/ do |text|
        step %(the stdout should contain "#{text}")
}
end
```

bem mais concisa e de acordo com o que a gem atende.

Bom, obrigado a quem atendeu as minhas dúvidas.